# init: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, delphi, firemonkey

I try to implement the new mandatory (in June) authentication services in my ios APP made with delphi Rio 10.3.3. for this I convert this class:

```
AS_EXTERN API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0), macos(10.15), tvos(13.0), watchos(6.0))
@interface ASAuthorizationController : NSObject

/*! @abstract Authorization requests that are being serviced by this controller
 */
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSArray<ASAuthorizationRequest *> *authorizationRequests;

/*! @abstract This delegate will be invoked upon completion of the authorization indicating success or failure.
 Delegate is required to receive the results of authorization.
 */
@property (nonatomic, weak, nullable) id <ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate> delegate;

/*! @abstract This delegate will be invoked upon needing a presentation context to display authorization UI.
 */
@property (nonatomic, weak, nullable) id <ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding> presentationContextProvider API_UNAVAILABLE(watchos);

/*! @abstract Initialize the controller with authorization requests.

 @param authorizationRequests At least one request should be provided. Requests of same type maybe honored in first in first out order
 */
- (instancetype)initWithAuthorizationRequests:(NSArray<ASAuthorizationRequest *> *)authorizationRequests NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

/*! @abstract Initiate the authorization flows.  Upon completion, the delegate will be called with either success or failure.
 Certain authorization flows may require a presentation context, the presentationContextProvider will be called to provider it.

 The instance will remain retained until the user completes the flow and the delegate callback is made.
 */
- (void)performRequests;

+ (instancetype)new NS_UNAVAILABLE;

- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;

@end
```

to this delphi class

```
  ASAuthorizationControllerClass = interface(NSObjectClass)
    ['{1FFA7BB5-DAA7-4FD5-A5B7-FE466A83A23F}']
  end;
  ASAuthorizationController = interface(NSObject)
    ['{214873D8-CCF0-42B8-A381-04BBCFB75269}']
    //function authorizationRequests : NSArray; cdecl;
    procedure setDelegate(delegate: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate); cdecl;
    function delegate : ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate; cdecl;
    procedure setPresentationContextProvider(presentationContextProvider: ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding); cdecl;
    function presentationContextProvider: ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding; cdecl;
    function initWithAuthorizationRequests(authorizationRequests: NSArray): ASAuthorizationController; cdecl;
    procedure performRequests; cdecl;
  end;
  TASAuthorizationController = class(TOCGenericImport<ASAuthorizationControllerClass, ASAuthorizationController>)  end;
  PASAuthorizationController = Pointer;
```

but the problem is that when I call `TASAuthorizationController.create` I receive this error:

> -[ASAuthorizationController init]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x283c23380

How can I create under delphi an instance of `ASAuthorizationController`? normally I must call `initWithAuthorizationRequests` but it's not marked with a (+) but with a (-) so it's mean it's not a static/class function so I need an instance of `ASAuthorizationController` to call it

Comment: Do  `ASAuthorizationController *target = [[ASAuthorizationController alloc] initWithAuthorizationRequests:@[...]]` in Objective-C. In Swift, it'd be: `let target = ASAuthorizationController.init(withAuthorizationRequest: [...])`

Comment: @Larme off course ! thanks you save me lot of time, this is the answer, use alloc instead of init

Comment: "with a (+) but with a (-) so it's mean it's not a static/class function so I need an instance of ASAuthorizationController to call it": Well `- (instancetype)init` is already an instance method. It's just that in Objective-C, it's usually `[[SomeClass alloc] init]` which is done which is the same as `[SomeClass new]`. In Swift, we don't "show the alloc", but it's the same.

Comment: @larme, thanks if you can put your comment in answer i will accept it it's perfect !